# saving data like 2.3214E7 into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

am new to postgresql (redshift)
i am copying CSV files from S3 to RedShift and there's an error about trying to save 2.35555E7 number into a `numeric    | 18, 0` column . what is the right datatype for this datum ?

thanks

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html I'd go for `double precision` , which is a standard 64 bits IEEE float.

Comment: works fine when I try: `# create table test (val numeric(18,0)); -- CREATE TABLE` -- `# insert into test values (2.35555e7);
-- INSERT 0 1`...

Comment: Running `select '2.35555E7'::numeric(18,0)` seems to work OK for me, suggesting that is a valid input for that data type. (Tested on both 8.3 and 9.2, so unlikely to be a version difference, but please do specify versions when asking such questions!)

Comment: "An error". And the error is, *exactly*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numeric (18,0)` implies a scale of zero, which is a way of saying no decimals -- it's a bit like a smaller bigint.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html

If you want to keep it as numeric, you want to use `numeric` instead -- with no precision or scale.

If not, just use a `real` or a `double precision` type, depending on the number of significant digits (6 vs 15, respectively) you want to keep around.

Your example data (2.35555E7) suggests you're using `real`, so probably try that one first.

---

Note: `select 2.35555E7::numeric(18,0)` works fine per the comments, but I assume there's some other data in your set that is causing issues.